# Is the Power BI Javascript API supported in Power BI Report Server?

Tags: powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I would like to know if the Power BI Javascript API is supported in Power BI Report Server. If Yes, then how?

Comment: PowerBI Javascript API is not supported in PowerBI Report Server. However, you can make the use of REST APIs for PowerBI Report Server.

Please go through the given references to get more information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi-report/